# Script not working after pageload

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using javascript to show reamaining character show for sms_textbox. which allow only 160 character.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            var characterLimit = 160;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#lblremaingCharacters").html(characterLimit);
                $("#txtmessage").bind("keyup", function () {
                    var characterInserted = $(this).val().length;
                    if (characterInserted > characterLimit) {
                        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, characterLimit));
                    }
                    var characterRemaining = characterLimit - characterInserted;
                    $("#lblremaingCharacters").html(characterRemaining);
                });
            });
        </script>
```

But this script working good only at page load, not working when other asp button click event fire.

Comment: Are you using **Update Panels** in your code??

Comment: keep your `characterLimit` variable inside `ready` scope.

Comment: Do you have a fiddlejs ? but maybe script is excuted many times try unbind before bind $("#txtmessage").unbind('keyup').bind("keyup", function () {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding script in **pageLoad** function in **aspx page** instead of $(document).ready like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var characterLimit = 160;
        function pageLoad() {
            $("#lblremaingCharacters").html(characterLimit);
            $("#txtmessage").bind("keyup", function () {
                var characterInserted = $(this).val().length;
                if (characterInserted > characterLimit) {
                    $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, characterLimit));
                }
                var characterRemaining = characterLimit - characterInserted;
                $("#lblremaingCharacters").html(characterRemaining);
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace characterLimit inside the document.ready function

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            var characterLimit = 160;
            $("#lblremaingCharacters").html(characterLimit);
```

Now the characterLimit will work like **global value** for all your events.

Now your script should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var characterLimit = 160;
            $("#lblremaingCharacters").html(characterLimit);
            $("#txtmessage").bind("keyup", function () {
                var characterInserted = $(this).val().length;
                if (characterInserted > characterLimit) {
                    $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, characterLimit));
                }
                var characterRemaining = characterLimit - characterInserted;
                $("#lblremaingCharacters").html(characterRemaining);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: same problem happen with this script also.

Comment: on key up try to alert the charcterLimit value and check

Comment: @ Gautam3164 i tried to alert charcterLimit. it is correct in alert msg. but the lable which i am showing for it it gets invisible on other any click event. i made it visible through javascript but still not working.

Comment: Then you need to bind other click event for that,if you asked like that

Answer (score 0):

Form your code i got that you are using `$(document).ready()`

You need to use

```
function pageLoad()
{
//Your Code
}
```

This will solve the problem